# How Do I Rehabilitate my Norfolk Island Pine?

Tags: plant-health, pines

We have a Norfolk Island Pine that was doing reasonably well...until we moved. Unsurprisingly, being packed up in a wardrobe box and driven across the country in a moving van (this was in December, so also in very cold weather) has not been good for it.

At the moment it is extremely droopy - most of the branches don't feel dry, but rather limp. We had to shift it in the soil, because it was no longer stable, which I expect is similar to being repotted.

At the moment, we're in a dry climate, and the plant is indoors, facing a window, and is watered ~ once a week or when the top inch or so of soil is dry. It hasn't shown much improvement in the past few weeks, and I was wondering if there is anything else we should be doing.

[image][image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is reaction to the cold and there is not much you can do in addition to providing bright diffuse light and consistent watering. The [Norfolk Island Pine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Araucaria_heterophylla) is quick to tell you about it's environment:

- grown outside in the tropics the leaves point upwards
- grown inside in lower light the leaves arch downwards
- too dry environment leads to whole branches being shed
- too cold leads to branches drooping down

With your plant it may slowly shed all the branches it has over time but the tip looks in good condition so it will continue to grow.

Do not cut this plant back. It is a tree with strong [apical dominance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apical_dominance) and only grows from the tip.

Comment: Well you "could" cut the tip. I have seen giant specimens of these trees in Florida, and it was clear that the top broke off at some point and the tree developed a new top. But it is ugly when this happens.

Comment: @Escoce That's right the tip will regrow but no need to do so unless the tip is dead.  It just ends up with a trunk with an "L" shape in it

Comment: Exactly what I was describing, but you did it better with L shape